# Close/Stop Activity before it is shown on Screen

Tags: android

This question is little weird.  But Important to me.

Basically I am using a library which shows a full screen Ad from inside of library. 
I have to add this activity into my app's manifest, otherwise when library tries to show AdActivity, my app crashes with message "Activity not registered in manifest".

Now I have no option other then registerring AdActivity in Manifest file. and now every time I open the application Library shows this Full screen ad and it is very irritating to users.

As my app is ad free, I would like to stop this activity to be shown!! is there any pointer I can start looking at. I feel there can be three option.

1) Remove AdActivity declaration from manifest and some how handle crash when Library starting AdActivity.

2) Declare AdActivity in Manifest and handle StartActivity call to not let it reach to AdActivity.

3) Let AdActivity be shown,but try to close it down asap from the app.

Please suggest something, I am scratching my head since hours.

Comment: Sounds like it is the whole point of the library to show ads. I bet there is a free alternative or a paid version of that library. Removing the ads most certainly violates the license.

Comment: Thanks for telling this,  it solves nothing.

Comment: You are asking, quite obviously, how to steal a software service on a site where most people live from creating software. Expect comments pointing to that. And I told you the possible solutions (not as answer as they technically aren't answers to your wrong question): Pay for what you want or find a free alternative. Honestly I am disappointed that you got answer tries at all.

Comment: See, I bought the application code from another developer, He gave me the app but he has this library which is showing ads, I dont want to show ads in my app. 
I asked him for complete source before paying. But he cheated me and give me some code as a library? Tell me should I give him more money and get cheated again? Anyways Thanks.

Comment: You are not allowed to steal from someone because someone else cheated on you.

Comment: I am not stealing, I am blocking something which i dint purchase as a package. you can also return goodies you get as a free gift!

Comment: I don't know if you make a living from developing software. When you do then someone using your code without paying means he thinks you don't deserve something to eat or a roof above your head. It is worse than stealing. You didn't buy a license for an ad-less version of that library. If someone else cheated on you then you have to sue THAT person. This is not about "life in general has to be fair and balanced".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering the AdActivity, but setting an intent filter that would prevent the AdActivity from being selected ?

Or you could register two activities, forcing android to show a picker for the AdActivity and your own (SkipAdActivity) so the User could at least choose to always run your SkipAdActivity.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about how can I prevent it to open,  by intent filter.

Comment: Tried adding Activity with same name/package name, Code is not getting compiled now. :)

Comment: Oh they must start it by class name then.. no neither of these will help you out

Comment: Thanks. No prob. Will try others way out. And will post solution here if any.

Answer (score 1):

First option seems to be the best you can do, you can basically try to wrap the call to the library that triggers the `AdActivity` start inside the try-catch block handling `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Comment: This seems intresting,  let's try it out.